# Load temp video and play

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation

I need to play continuously a video stored inside the temp directory.

```
func setVideo(url vid: String!) {

    let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory()

    let tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("tempMovie\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)").appendingPathExtension("mp4")

    let tempFile = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: [directory])


    let file = vid.components(separatedBy: ".")

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(tempURL)", ofType:file[2]) else {
        debugPrint( "\(file.joined(separator: ".")) not found with path: \(file[0] + "." + file[1])")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player?.play()
        }
    })

}
```

The video location and file url is:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E7D12401-F147-4905-83BE-72909F91E004/tmp/tempMovie1501672791.33525.mp4
```

The continuous loop part works from a previous project however I can't seem to get the temp stored video to load inside the player. I've tried to get the temp directory manually but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the video from tmp to Documents directory worked for me.

This is how you do it:

```
    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("filename.fileExtension")

        do {

            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: previousTempLocation, to: destinationURL)

        } catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription)}

    let player = AVPlayer(url: destinationURL)
```

Apple says this on /tmp directory

> Use this directory to write temporary files that do not need to
>   persist between launches of your app. Your app should remove files
>   from this directory when they are no longer needed; however, the
>   system may purge this directory when your app is not running.

Apple also recommends this for user data

> Put user data in Documents/. User data generally includes any files
>   you might want to expose to the user—anything you might want the user
>   to create, import, delete or edit. Video and audio apps may even include
>   files that the user has downloaded to watch or listen to later.